# Positioning problems with top:

Tags: html, css

I am building my first website/portfolio http://patrykponichtera.com/ and i encountered a problem i can't solve

If you visit my website and you scroll at the bottom you'll see i've inlcuded a world map image, and you can see that the background image is cut off and leaves the bottom white, what triggers the problem is the `float:right;` of the world map, if i remove the `float:right;` it works fine

Also there's a huge gap between the map and the bottom, which i don't want and it's caused by a `top:-100px;` applied to the circle profile image and a `top:-230px;` applied to the info div

How can i solve those issues?

Comment: are you trying to just remove the white space beneath the map for fully show the map?

Comment: i want to remove the unused space at the bottom, the map should be the lowest part of the website, and i want the background image to extend to the bottom aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what if you change your css to this?

```
#world-map {
position: absolute;
margin-right: 30px;
width: 50%;
height: auto;
right: 0;
bottom:-5px;
}

#content {
height: auto;
width: 100%;
background-color: #2f2f2f;
background-image: url('images/asfalt.png');
background-repeat: repeat;
position: relative;

}


 <div id="world-map"><img alt="Worldmap" src="images/dotted-worldmap.svg"></div>
```

Working html code...

```
<div id="content">

    <div id="profile">
        <img id="profile-image" src="images/profile_pic.png">
    </div>

    <div id="info">
        <div id="title-wrapper">
            <h1 id="patryk-title" class="main-title">Patryk </h1> <h1 id="ponichtera-title" class="main-title">Ponichtera</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="profession">
            <div id="skew-line-1" class="skew-line"></div>
            <div id="skew-line-2" class="skew-line"></div>
            <div id="skew-line-3" class="skew-line"></div>
            <div id="profession-content1" class="skew-line">
                <h3 class="skew-text">Graphic Designer</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="profession-content2" class="skew-line">
                <h3 class="skew-text">Android Developer</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="xp-years">
            <div id="skew-line-3" class="skew-line"></div>
            <div id="skew-line-4" class="skew-line"></div>
            <div id="skew-line-5" class="skew-line"></div>
            <div id="xp-years-content" class="skew-line">
                <h3 class="skew-text">5 years xp in graphics</h3>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="biography">
            <p class="bio">My name is Patryk Ponichtera, I was born in Łomża, Poland in June 1990.</p><p>
            </p><p class="bio">I'm a self taught graphic designer and Android developer.</p><p>
            </p><p class="bio">I've been working in graphics for 5 years,  in both 3D and 2D.</p><p>
            </p><p class="bio">Games and movies were my main inspiration and motivation to learn graphic design.</p><p>
            </p><p class="bio">At the end of 2010 i've purchased my first android device, which led me to android app development, I've started by helping a friend write an app for his High School graduation exam.</p><p>
            </p><p class="bio">In August 2012 I've released my first app Double Counter to the Play Store, and in September 2012 I've released my second app Wakey.</p><p>

        </p></div>

    </div> <!-- #info -->

    <div id="world-map"><img alt="Worldmap" src="images/dotted-worldmap.svg"></div>

</div><!-- #content -->
```

Comment: better, the bottom space is removed, but i have still the part with no background image left, i've updated the website with your css

Comment: Wait, do you want to see the map or should it be overlayed by the dark gray background? I made it so that is shows. Do you want it to be fully covered?

Comment: The world map should be on top of the dark background, it should be barely visible

Comment: Adding a 'padding-bottom:250px;' to '#info' solves the problem, but it's not the ideal solution because my website will be dynamically resizable and it will leave a big gap at the bottom

Comment: Well remove the padding you just added and see my updated answer. I made changes to both world map and content

Comment: Ok one more thing. put the IMG inside a div. See my update answer. Then it works as you want I believe, with the CSS above and img inside a div.

Comment: Not really what i wanted, i wanted to stretch down the background, not put the map up there but i like it better your way so i'll keep it :)
Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: Ok no problem but Not sure what you meant by map **up** there. With the code I have posted above it's at the bottom where I thought you wanted it. Take note of the div world-map in the html I pasted. I moved it just inside content. You can see it here. http://i.imgur.com/7wbdAwV.png So above should work for you if the screen shot is how you wanted it.